# Vectorial sum of two parallel and discordant forces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, statics

To obtain the resultant force, colored in purple, of two parallel and concordant forces $\vec{F_1}$ and $\vec{F_2}$, I apply a vector $\boldsymbol f$ (colored in brown) to the bar $AB$; similarly there will be a vector  $-\boldsymbol f$ that when added to $\boldsymbol f$ will give me with the null vector involving no movement of the bar $AB$ and the correct distances $d_1$ and $d_2$.

> Now I do not remember the construction of two parallel and discordant forces.

Thank you in advance if you give me a complete solution or the text of a book or from a pdf where the constructions are done to find the resulting **sum vector of two parallel and discordant forces**.

PS: for the drawing you can use Mathcha: https://www.mathcha.io/editor

[image]

Comment: cute, but what is the physical significance?

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent When you have two parallel and concordant forces the point of application of the resultant lies inside the rod $AB$ and the sum is given by the sum of the two forces.

Comment: Is the body free-floating? What is special about $O$? What is this construction trying to achieve? What do you want to know about this construction, the picture you showed seems to be enough knowledge to do the construction? I don't want to be nitpicky but if you incorporate the answers to these questions in your question you are more likely to get a satisfying answer.

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion On the construction that I have drawn everything is clear. I would be interested in understanding where $O$ is located with the relative distances $d_1$ and $d_2$ when the assigned forces are not concordant but discordant in direction.

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion - Point _O_ is the BaryCenter of the applied forces.

Answer (score 4):

I have [answered this question before](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/756591/392) but it is not an exact duplicate and the answer did not get awarded.

So you want to find point *O* where you draw the combined force from.

**Point *O* is the barycenter of the applied loads, parallel or not.**

What does this mean?

- In 2D given the locations $x_1$ and $x_2$ of two parallel forces $F_1$ and $F_2$ from the coordinate origin, we are looking for the location $x_O$ of the line of action of the combined force $F_O = F_1 + F_2$.

  [image: fig1]

  This is found by solving the following barycenter equations

  $$\begin{aligned}
    F_O &= F_1 + F_2 \\
    x_O F_O & = x_1 F_1 + x_2 F_2 \\
   \end{aligned} $$

  The above can be viewed as the sum of forces and torques about the origin for the combined loads and the individual loads must be equal to each other. The solution to the above is

  $$x_O = \frac{x_1 F_1 + x_2 F_2}{F_1+F_2} $$

  and the neat geometry trick shown in the question does exactly this which can be shown with some geometry.
- In 3D we take our clue about the sum of the forces and torques (or moments in this case) and solve the following *vector* problem to solve for the barycenter $\boldsymbol{r}_O$

  $$\begin{aligned}
    \boldsymbol{F}_O &= \boldsymbol{F}_1 + \boldsymbol{F}_2 \\
    \boldsymbol{r}_O \times \boldsymbol{F}_0 & = \boldsymbol{r}_1 \times \boldsymbol{F}_1 + \boldsymbol{r}_2 \times \boldsymbol{F}_2 \\
   \end{aligned} $$

  where $\boldsymbol{r}_i$ are a location the forces $\boldsymbol{F}_i$ go through, and $\times$ is the vector cross product. The solution is

  $$\begin{aligned}\boldsymbol{M}_{O} & =\boldsymbol{r}_{1}\times\boldsymbol{F}_{1}+\boldsymbol{r}_{2}\times\boldsymbol{F}_{2}\\
  \boldsymbol{r}_{O} & =\frac{\boldsymbol{F}_{O}\times\boldsymbol{M}_{O}}{\|\boldsymbol{F}_{O}\|^{2}}
  \end{aligned}$$

  with the caveat that the resulting point *O* is the point on the line of action of $\boldsymbol{F}_O$ that is geometrically closest to the origin. Any displacement along the line of action is ignored due to the cross-products.

Comment: Quick question - just to clarify something - when it comes to statics (in the context of engineering mechanics), there seem to be a lot of unstated assumptions (its sort of like Newton's laws with extra semantics). Is the assumption that the two forces (loads) are caused by & proportional to two masses external to the beam (which are modeled as point masses on the beam)? And the barycenter is actually the COM of those two point masses? Cause otherwise the notion of barycenter of forces doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Barycenter = center of gravity but not necessarily for forces of gravity. Any force system has an equivalent location that the combined forces go through. For statics Newton's 3rd law means the combined loading of the supports must equal the applied load in magnitude, direction and location.

Answer (score 3):

Take the sum of the torques about point $O$, you obtain

$$\sum_\tau=F_1\,d_1-F_2\,d_2=0\\
\text{with}\quad d_2=L-d_1\quad\Rightarrow\\
d_1=L\frac{F_2}{F_1+F_2} 
$$

Answer (score 0):

**My answer**:

1. We add two vectors of equal modulus and
   opposite direction ($F$) and ($-F$) applied
   respectively to the points of application of $F_1$ and
   $F_2$ (the operation thus done does not alter the system
   of forces, since the two added forces will
   cancel out);
2. we compose $F_1$ with $F$ obtaining $R_1$;
3. We compose $F_2$ with ($-F$) obtaining $R_2$;
4. We move $R_1$ and $R_2$ along their action lines
   until they have the same point of application
   $O$;
5. Compounding, now, $R_1$ and $R_2$ yields the
   final resultant $R$;
6. The point of application of the resultant $OR$ is
   represented by the intersection of the line
   of action of $R$ and the segment $AB$.

[image]

Comment: Why there is a downvote? What is the reason?

Comment: Another downvote. Why?