# Parallel and concordant forces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, statics

[image]

I translate into English what is written in Italian in the adopted text.

> Two forces are parallel if they have parallel lines of action; two parallel forces are concordant if they have the same direction. The resultant of two parallel and concordant forces $\vec{F_1}$ and $\vec{F_2}$, applied at points $A$ and $B$ respectively, is a force that has the same direction and direction as $\vec{F_1}$ and $\vec{F_2}$ and intensity equal to the sum of the intensities of the two forces: $R=F_1+F_2$. The point of application $C$ of the resultant divides the segment $AB$ into two segments $AC$ and $CB$ whose ratio is in inverse proportion to that of $F_1$ and $F_2$:
> $$AC:CB=F_2:F_1 \tag 1$$
> The resultant then is internal to the two forces and its point of application is closer to the force of greater intensity as shown in Figure 13.

**From this discussion I did not understand why the proportion $(1)$ is true and the reason for this.**

Comment: Why my question must be closed?????? what Is the reason?

Comment: Possible Duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/761824/392 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/756591/392, none awarded.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou duplicated? Very strange. I have not used the momentum. It Is wrong.

Comment: The awarded answer does use the torques (momentum is incorrect term here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

$AC:CB=F_2:F_1$

then

$F_1 \times AC = F_2 \times CB$

In other words, $F_1$ and $F_2$ have equal and opposite moments about point $C$, so the net torque of $F_1$ and $F_2$ about point $C$ is zero. This is why point $C$ is chosen as the point of application of the resultant force.

Comment: But in the chapter of the forces there is not explained the momentum or torque. Is there another way to explain my question? Thank you.

Comment: @Sebastiano Not momentum - *moments*. Just think of it like a balance. If the line $AB$ is a see-saw then the point $C$ is the pivot about which the two forces $F_1$ and $F_2$ balance each other.

Answer (score 2):

[image: f5]

Let D be the C.O.M.

Then,

${\tau}_1=F_1 AD$ and ${\tau}_2=F_2 DB$.

$\tau_{net} = \tau_1 - \tau_2$

Also,
$\tau_{net}=(F_1 + F_2) CD$

Equating both equations we get:
$$CD=\frac{ AD \times F_1 - DB \times F_2}{F_1 + F_2}$$

From this,

$$AC= \frac{F_2 \times AB}{F_1 + F_2}$$

And,
$$CB=\frac{F_1 \times AB}{F_1 + F_2}$$

Finally,
$$\frac{AC}{CB}=\frac{F_2}{F_1}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.